# Pointer to array of structs element field in a function

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers, struct

I have a function which searches for extrema in some data array. It takes pointer to data, some parameters and a pointer to struct array where the result is stored. The function returns the length of the resulting struct array.

```
int FindPeaks(float *data, int WindowWidth, float threshold, struct result *p)
{
    int RightBorder = 0;
    int LeftBorder = 0;

    bool flag = 1;

    int i = 0;
    int k = 0;

    while(1)
    {
        flag = 1;
        if (WindowWidth >= 200) cout << "Your window is larger than the signal! << endl";
        if (i >= 200) break;
        if ((i + WindowWidth) < 200) RightBorder = i + WindowWidth;
        if ((i - WindowWidth) >= 0) LeftBorder = i - WindowWidth;
        for(int j = LeftBorder; j <= RightBorder; j ++)
        {
            if (*(data + i) < *(data + j))
            {
                flag = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (flag && *(data + i) >= threshold && i != 0 && i != 199)
        {
            struct result pointer = p + k;
            pointer.amplitude = *(data + i);
            pointer.position = i;
            i = i + WindowWidth;
            k++;
        }
        else
        {
            i ++;
        }
    }

    return k;
}
```

I'm confused with a reference to i-th struct field to put the result in there. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: ***"I'm confused with a reference to i-th struct field to put the result in there. "*** - What do you mean by that?

Comment: `struct result pointer = p + k;`:, is have a feeling it should be: `struct result* pointer = p + k;`

Comment: I cannot compile this line. Troubles with setting pointer to i-th amplitude:
pointer.amplitude = *(data + i);

Comment: _"a pointer to struct array"_ Ew this is all very C-like. You're even using the `struct` prefix. What resource are you using to learn C++?

Comment: @Dankevich: We know you "cannot compile this line". But repeating the vague problem statement doesn't help..

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I actually didn't know the error, only when the OP pointed it out did i realize the error

Comment: @ArnavBorborah: But you were wrong.

Comment: Please show the calling code of `FindPeaks`... we can't even see if you input proper initialized array behind your pointer parameters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to be too smart with use of pointers, so your code won't even compile.

Instead of using `*(data + i)` or `*(data+j)` everywhere, use `data[i]` or `data[j]`.   They're equivalent, and the second is often more readable when working with an array (assuming the `data` passed by the caller is actually (the address of the first element of) an array of `float`).

The problem you asked about is this code

```
struct result pointer = p + k;
pointer.amplitude = *(data + i);
pointer.position = i;
```

where `p` is a pointer to `struct result` passed to the function as argument.  In this case, `pointer` actually needs to be a true pointer.   Assuming you want it to point at `p[k]` (rather than creating a separate `struct result`) you might need to do

```
struct result *pointer = p + k;    /*   equivalently &p[k] */
pointer->amplitude = data[i];
pointer->position = i;
```

This will get the code to compile.   Note that you have not described what the function is actually supposed to achieve, so I have not bothered to check if the code actually does anything sensible.

Note that you're actually (mis)using C techniques in C++.   There are much better alternatives in modern C++, such as using standard containers.

Comment: I dunno about "too smart".

Comment: @StoryTeller - I said "trying to be too start", not "being too smart".   The meaning is totally different.

Comment: `struct result` sounds really C-like.

Comment: @Peter, I realize now that sarcasm is clearly not meant for this medium.

Comment: @Bob__ - yes, that's true.   But that's the way the question was written.  I am not trying to fix ALL the problems in the OPs code, from a C++ perspective.   Because every fix I include will need more explanation .... and make it harder for the OP to understand the answer.

Comment: @Peter, the code maybe imperfect, but now it does perfectly what I need from it. Tell me, please, what else is in there? I am a newbie, I don't see everything yet.

Comment: That's really hard to explain in full, without writing an essay (which is not suited to this format), Dankevich.  However, in the declaration `struct result *pointer = p+k`, the `struct` keyword is not needed at all in C++ (but is in C).   It's one of the reasons others have commented that your code is C and not C++.   Additionally, in modern C++, you would rarely (possibly never) need to use a pointer or an array at all in ANY of your code .... if you learn about C++ standard containers like `vector`.